# Child states in alpha-beta pruning

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with the alpha-beta pruning algorithm from Wikipedia:

```
function alphabeta(node, depth, α, β, Player)         
if  depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
    return the heuristic value of node
if  Player = MaxPlayer
    for each child of node
        α := max(α, alphabeta(child, depth-1, α, β, not(Player) ))     
        if β ≤ α
            break                             (* Beta cut-off *)
    return α
else
    for each child of node
        β := min(β, alphabeta(child, depth-1, α, β, not(Player) ))     
        if β ≤ α
            break                             (* Alpha cut-off *)

    return β
```

Specifically the recursive call of alpha-beta. I keep getting a SegFault error on the first pass of alpha-beta.

Here is my alpha-beta function:

```
int alphabeta(int board[9], int depth, int alpha, int beta, bool max_player) {

    int score = 0;
    max_player = true;

    if(depth == 0){
        return score;
    }

    if(max_player) {
        alpha = INT_MIN;
        while (depth != 0) {
        score = alphabeta(board[9], depth - 1, alpha, beta, !max_player); <--- where error originates
            alpha = MAX(alpha, score );
            if (beta <= alpha) break;
        }
        return alpha;
    }
    else {
        beta = INT_MAX;
        while (depth != 0) {
            score = alphabeta(board[9], depth - 1, alpha, beta, !max_player);
            beta = MIN(beta, score );
            if (beta <= alpha) break;
        }
        return beta;
    }
}
```

with the overall implementation here:

```
# include "stdio.h"
# include "limits.h"

int MAX (int x, int y) {
    if (x > y) {
        return x;
    }
    else {
        return y;
    }
}

int MIN (int x, int y) {
    if (x < y) {
        return x;
    }
    else {
        return y;
    }
}


char gridChar(int i) {
    switch(i) {
        case -1:
            return 'X';
        case 0:
            return ' ';
        case 1:
            return 'O';
    }
}

void draw(int b[9]) {
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n",gridChar(b[0]),gridChar(b[1]),gridChar(b[2]));
    printf("---+---+---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n",gridChar(b[3]),gridChar(b[4]),gridChar(b[5]));
    printf("---+---+---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n",gridChar(b[6]),gridChar(b[7]),gridChar(b[8]));
}

int win(const int board[9]) {
    //determines if a player has won, returns 0 otherwise.
    unsigned wins[8][3] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if(board[wins[i][0]] != 0 &&
           board[wins[i][0]] == board[wins[i][1]] &&
           board[wins[i][0]] == board[wins[i][2]])
            return board[wins[i][2]];
    }
    return 0;
}

int alphabeta(int board[9], int depth, int alpha, int beta, bool max_player) {

    int score = 0;
    max_player = true;

    if(depth == 0){
        return score;
    }

    if(max_player) {
        alpha = INT_MIN;
        while (depth != 0) {
        score = alphabeta(board[9], depth - 1, alpha, beta, !max_player);
            alpha = MAX(alpha, score );
            if (beta <= alpha) break;
        }
        return alpha;
    }
    else {
        beta = INT_MAX;
        while (depth != 0) {
            score = alphabeta(board[9], depth - 1, alpha, beta, !max_player);
            beta = MIN(beta, score );
            if (beta <= alpha) break;
        }
        return beta;
    }
}


void computerMove(int board[9]) {
    int move = -1;
    int score = -2;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        if(board[i] == 0) {
            board[i] = 1;
            int tempScore = -alphabeta(board[9],6, -10000, 10000, true);
            board[i] = 0;
            if(tempScore > score) {
                score = tempScore;
                move = i;
            }
        }
    }
    //returns a score based on minimax tree at a given node.
    board[move] = 1;
}


void playerMove(int board[9]) {
    int move = 0;
    do {
        printf("\nInput move ([0..8]): ");
        scanf("%d", &move);
        printf("\n");
    } while (move >= 9 || move < 0 && board[move] == 0);
    board[move] = -1;
}

int main() {
    int board[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    //computer squares are 1, player squares are -1.
    printf("Computer: O, You: X\nPlay (1)st or (2)nd? ");
    int player=0;
    scanf("%d",&player);
    printf("\n");
    unsigned turn;
    for(turn = 0; turn < 9 && win(board) == 0; ++turn) {
        if((turn+player) % 2 == 0)
            computerMove(board);
        else {
            draw(board);
            playerMove(board);
        }
    }
    switch(win(board)) {
        case 0:
            printf("A draw. How droll.\n");
            break;
        case 1:
            draw(board);
            printf("You lose.\n");
            break;
        case -1:
            printf("You win. Inconceivable!\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that my implementation is not correctly identifying the "child nodes" of the current board, but I am lost as to how to code that with regard to an array of integers. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `score = alphabeta(board[9], depth - 1, alpha, beta, !max_player);` -- Tells us what you think the first parameter, `board[9]`,  is supposed to denote.  Your issue has nothing to do with alpha-beta pruning and everything to do with improper usage of C++.

Comment: Also, C++ has `std::min` and `std::max` functions.  There is no need to write your own versions.

Answer (score 0):

One error is here (and you are making similar mistakes in other places in your code):

`score = alphabeta(board[9], depth - 1, alpha, beta, !max_player);`

The first parameter, `board[9]` is accessing an out-of-bounds element of the `board` array.  You're sending a single `int`, namely `board[9]`, but `board[9]` is an element that is out-of-bounds of `board`, thus you're invoking undefined behavior.

I don't know what your intentions are with the code above, but if you are trying to pass the buffer pointed to by `board`:

`score = alphabeta(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, !max_player);`

If you're trying to pass the last element of the `board`:

`score = alphabeta(board[8], depth - 1, alpha, beta, !max_player);`

---

In addition, if you're not aware, function prototypes like this:

```
int win(const int board[9])
```

are no different than this:

```
int win(const int* board)
```

Arrays decay to pointers -- you are not actually passing an array.

[The example here](http://ideone.com/a30PGn) shows what the program would look like when corrected (the runtime error is due to missing input).

You also have some very suspicious code, for example:

```
while (move >= 9 || move < 0 && board[move] == 0);
```

If `move < 0`, you are accessing `board` with a negative index, which is another out-of-bounds access.

Comment: My intention was for alphabeta to take in the current board setup and use it as the "root node" for a new search.

Comment: That may be your intention, but that is not what your code is doing.  The answer explains what it is you're actually doing, and how to correct it.